# Questions on equation of log linear regression

Tags: logarithm, arithmetic

I have been asked to check over a paper. The paper is using log linear regression. In the following log linear equation, $x$ is the dependent variable, $y$ is a continuous covariate, $z$ is a categorical variable taking value of 0 or 1 for yes/no. $A$ and $B$ are regression coefficients and $C$ is the intercept. The equation is:

$\log(x) = A \times \log(y) + Bz + C$

$\log$ here is natural logarithm.

Solving this equation for x, the writer got

$x = y^A \times e^Bz \times e^C$

For some reason, I feel that's not correct. Can someone please tell me if this is correct? If not, what would be the correct derivation of equation 2 from equation 1?

Comment: the middle term should be $e^{Bz}$

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried solving the equation in terms of $x$?

\begin{align*}
\log(x)&=A\log(y)+Bz+C\\
\end{align*}
so take the exponential of both sides to get

\begin{align*}
x&=e^{A\log y+Bz+C}\\
&\\
&=e^{A\log y}e^{Bz}e^{C}\\
&\\
&=e^{\log y^A}e^{Bz}e^{C}\\
&\\
&=y^Ae^{Bz}e^{C}
\end{align*}

and so this should be the solution.